# elasticsearch -- sort by distance and price/rating

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geolocation

I'm trying to compose a query that'd be sorted by `_geo_distance` in the first place and by `price` or `rating` secondly. Basically, what I want to achieve is the closest results with the highest rating/price.

Here's an example query:

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          bool: {
            should: [
              {
                match_all: {

                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      filter: [
        {
          bool: {

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  sort: [
    {
      _geo_distance: {
        location: {
          lat: 51.840191,
          lon: 61.581038
        },
        order: 'asc',
        unit: 'km',
        distance_type: 'sloppy_arc'
      }
    },
    {
      rating: {
        order: 'desc'
      }
    }
  ],
  size: 10,
  from: 0,
  _source: [
    'id',
    '_score',
    'location',
    'price',
    'rating'
  ]
}
```

The problem is that the result contains only the closest results with low ratings and prices.

My question is whether it is possible to adjust the sorting somehow, or should I attach a `function_score` query to replace the sorting?

Comment: It sounds like you are not sure what _closest results with the highest rating/price_ means :-).

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a compromise between rating and location...

Comment: What you need is a `decay` function and the ES documentation gives the example of hotels scoring based on location: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay. I suggest giving a good read of that entire documentation section and perform some tests with your data.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I think I understand the problem. Though I'm a little bit confused as to what parameters I should provide for the decay function. I don't really have a `scale` for distance or rating/price. I just want them to be scored appropriately, i.e. the lowest distance and the highest rating gets the highest score.

Comment: Sorry, meant `origin`, too.